# Get all elements within specific section

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have below html strcuture:

```
<div>    
    <div class="flw__panel__col--12 flw__container__col--12 formSection__col--12">
      <div>
         <div><div class="EmptyDiv"></div><button   onClick={onAddClick} id="RequestNewOrgBtn_prefix-1" class="ui primary button">Request New External Org</button><div></div></div>
      </div>

      <div>
        <div><div class="EmptyDiv"></div><button   onClick={onAddClick} id="RequestNewOrgBtn_prefix-2" class="ui primary button">Request New External Org</button><div></div></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flw__panel__col--12 flw__container__col--12 formSection__col--12">
    <div>
        <div><div class="EmptyDiv"></div><button   onClick={onAddClick} id="RequestNewOrgBtn_prefix-3" class="ui primary button">Request New External Org</button><div></div></div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div><div class="EmptyDiv"></div><button   onClick={onAddClick} id="RequestNewOrgBtn_prefix-4" class="ui primary button">Request New External Org</button><div></div></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when i click on a specific button, it executes below function which gives selected index of all elements in above html that begins "RequestNewOrgBtn", however I want to retrieve the index of the element within div class "flw__panel__col--12 flw__container__col--12 formSection__col--12", but the class isn't unique, its common. I'm not able to figure it out how do it via parent div since parent div's class are same?

```js
    const onAddClick = (e: any) => {
            // find index of selected elememt
            let cusid_ele = document.querySelectorAll("[id^=RequestNewOrgBtn]");
            const selectedElementId = e.target.id;
            for (let i = 0; i < cusid_ele.length; i++){
                if( cusid_ele[i].getAttribute("id") === selectedElementId){
                    setSelectedIndex(i);
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: What do you mean by `index` here? if you want the immediate `parent` did you try using `closest`?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: I meant when I click on button 3 in above html, it should give me the index of button 3 and 4 id because both belongs to one div with class "flw__panel__col--12 flw__container__col--12 formSection__col--12", and similarly when I click on 2 button then 1 and 2 index not 3 and 4, I dont think closest will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the below snippet, it will get all the buttons in the closest parent and give you the indices of those buttons extracting from their ids.

```
const onAddClick = (e) => {
      console.log(
      Array.from(
        e.target.closest(".flw__panel__col--12.flw__container__col--12.formSection__col--12")
        .querySelectorAll("[id^=RequestNewOrgBtn]"))
        .map(a=>a.id.split('').pop()))
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood your question right. It seems like you have 2 divs stored under each class, hence you can assume that the even number is always the latter index, while odd is the preceding one:

```js
function onAddClick(e) {
    const indexGroup = [];
    const currentIndex = Number(e?.id.slice(-1));
    console.log(`CURRENT INDEX: `, currentIndex);
    if (currentIndex % 2) {
        // odd number (first)
        indexGroup.push(currentIndex, currentIndex + 1);
    } else {
        // even number (last)
        indexGroup.push(currentIndex - 1, currentIndex);
    }
    console.log(`GROUP OF INDEXES: `, indexGroup);
    return indexGroup;
};
```

```html
    <div>
        <div class="flw__panel__col--12 flw__container__col--12 formSection__col--12">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div class="EmptyDiv"></div><button onClick={onAddClick(this)} id="RequestNewOrgBtn_prefix-1"
                        class="ui primary button">Request New External Org</button>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div>
                    <div class="EmptyDiv"></div><button onClick={onAddClick(this)} id="RequestNewOrgBtn_prefix-2"
                        class="ui primary button">Request New External Org</button>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flw__panel__col--12 flw__container__col--12 formSection__col--12">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div class="EmptyDiv"></div><button onClick={onAddClick(this)} id="RequestNewOrgBtn_prefix-3"
                        class="ui primary button">Request New External Org</button>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div>
                <div>
                    <div class="EmptyDiv"></div><button onClick={onAddClick(this)} id="RequestNewOrgBtn_prefix-4"
                        class="ui primary button">Request New External Org</button>
                    <div></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```